# case insensitive in regex in postgresql query

Tags: regex, postgresql, case-insensitive

I want to search for a list of name through records of another table
i want that my regex be case insensitive, but I can not make it work!

```
SELECT id
  FROM "regexfreeFlickrFullInfo"
  where tags ~ 'tower\s?\*?bridge'  or title ~ 'tower\s?\*?bridge' or descriptio ~ 'tower\s?\*?bridge'  order by id asc;
```

here is my query, I have tested by i, but it did not work!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You must use `~*` instead of `~`.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to support case sensitive and insensitive queries without changing the query itself, you may change the behavior of the operator with the [Regular Expression Metasyntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX). *They can override the case-sensitivity behavior implied by a regex operator.*.

```
tags ~ 'Case Sensitive'
tags ~ '(?i)case insensitive'
tags ~* 'case insensitive'
tags ~* '(?c)Case Sensitive'
```